# Should I increase C or Gamma to get rid of bubbles in Support Vector Machine

Tags: python, svm, data-science

I am wondering what I should do when I want to get rid of bubbles from SVM. Do I increase C or increase Gamma?

Comment: Increase C. Or Gamma. Or both.

Comment: What if I decrease Gamma, will the bubbles disappear? Or this will cause more bubbles

Comment: It might. Or it might not.

Answer (score 0):

If you increase value of C it makes your application to classify more correctly but makes your application more complex(as more features participates in classification). And value of gamma influences training examples, so these values are dependent on your dataframe and feature selection(dense or sparse).
Hope it helps....